# SFTP Can view directory but cannot write

Tags: server, sftp

I have setup SFTP and I am trying to jail the user in a specific directory. Currently the user can login, and view the jailed directory. However, they cannot view, write or modify any files. A bit of background:

Folder for user: `/home/FTP/user`

Folder permissions:

755 for `/home/FTP/user`

755 for `/home/FTP`

Folder is owned by root.

Whenever I change the user from root to anything else or the permission level, I get blocked from logging in. Please help, I've searched for answers but have not found something that solves mine!

Answer (score 0):

## Some simple potential fixes

### Make User Account on Host Machine

On the host machine where the /home/FTP directory is located, make sure that `<username>` has a User Account and password.

### Make User Owner of Directory on Host Machine

On the host machine where the /home/FTP/`<username>` directory is located, make `<username>` the owner and group of this directory, recursively:

```
chown -R <username>:<username> /home/FTP/<username>
```

- -R, --recursive        operate on files and directories recursively